# Security implications of redirecting to an unescaped URL after login

Tags: security, passport.js, redirect, url-encoding

Do we need to unescape a URL that we have accepted from the user app for the purpose of redirecting to (say if the login succeeds, as in this question)? Are they any security vulnerabilities otherwise?

Longer question (code review) :-

While implementing facebook login on my webapp (with passportjs), I came across a following implementation for a small middleware function which sets the return URL in the session.

```
function checkReturnTo(req, res, next) {
  var returnTo = req.query['returnTo'];
  if (returnTo) {
    req.session.returnTo = querystring.unescape(returnTo);
  }
  next();
}
```

What if I don't unescape the 'returnTo' url above?

```
req.session.returnTo = returnTo;
```

The code works fine in both the cases. I tried to google, but could not find any specific exploits via a redirect URL. I thought it would make a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed [security issues with unrestricted redirects after login](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet), but escaping and unescaping the URL has nothing to do with them.

In general, if your framework already correctly extracts and unescapes URL parameters, there's no need to unescape them a second time (unless, of course, the code that generates the login URL redundantly double-escapes the redirect URL for some reason). However, I'm not specifically familiar with the framework you're using, so I can't tell for sure if one might be needed here for some odd reason.